# Span addClass not working ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a span like this `<span class="join-event to-join">join event</span>`.
I use this function to do something with the click via AJAX.

But in the success function I can't seem to add a class to that clicked span.

```
function accept() {

    $(".to-join").click(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr("data-event");

        $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: "../assets/js/ajax/toggle-events.php",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function() {

                alert("good job");
                $(this).addClass("joined");

            },

            error: function () {

                alert("fail");

            }

        });

    });

}
```

Comment: `$(this)` in success callback is not the `$(this)` you expect.

Comment: How can I get the $(this) that I expect then? Is there a solution for it?

Comment: Use `.bind` or create a reference like `var $self = $(this);` and use `$self` in callback, or pass addtional option `context : this` to `$.ajax`

Comment: You will have to refer to your element again with `$(".to-join")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `context` option of ajax method:

```
context: this,
```

> **context** Type: PlainObject This object will be the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that
>   represents the Ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged
>   with the settings passed to $.ajax).

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `$(this)` as variable outside the ajax call, this inside ajax will refers to `jqXHR` object

```
function accept() {    
    $(".to-join").click(function() {    
        var id = $(this).attr("data-event"),
              $this=$(this);    
        $.ajax({    
            type: "post",
            url: "../assets/js/ajax/toggle-events.php",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function() {    
                alert("good job");
                $this.addClass("joined");    
            },    
            error: function () {    
                alert("fail");    
            }    
        });    
    });    
}
```

Comment: The key thing to note here is that `this` is different in the ajax call because it's being used in a function, a different function from `accept()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".to-join").click(function() {
        var span = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr("data-event");

        $.ajax({

            type: "post",
            url: "../assets/js/ajax/toggle-events.php",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function() {

                alert("good job");
                span.addClass("joined");

            },

            error: function () {

                alert("fail");

            }

        });

    });
```